# Linked List ruby, the Node and LInkedlist class doesnt work properly

Tags: ruby

I have some issues with this code, so, I'm trying to make a linked list but with the first variable I get the next issue:

```
nodo.rb:34 in 'initialize': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

So, the Node class have the actual node and the link, and LinkedList the size and the header.
The problem comes when I try to add a new value but I receive the issue. So I dont know how to fix this problem. I will receive any help you could give me.

```
class Node
        def intialize(data,ref = nil)
        @data = data
        @refe = refe
    end

    def get_data
        return @data
    end

    def set_data(newdata)
        @dato = newdata
    end

    def get_ref
        return @ref
    end

    def set_ref(newref)
        @ref = newref
    end
end

class Linkedlist
    def initialize 
        @size = 0
        @header = nil
    end

    def add_var(value)
        @aize = @size + 1

        if @header == nil
                @header = Node.new(value)  #the issue comes here, in the moment when I try to make a new class of Node
        else
        nodeActual = @header
            while nodeActual.get_ref != nil
                nodeActual = nodeActual.get_ref
            end
        nodeActual.set_ref(Node.new(value))
        end
    end

    #def  print_list

    #end

    def get_size
        return @size
    end
end

list = Linkedlist.new
stop = nil

while stop != -1
    a = gets.chomp 
    if a.to_i == -1
        stop = -1
    else
        list.add_var(a)
    end
end
#list.print_list
```

Comment: As an aside, your variable names are all over the place.  Be sure that you're being consistent in all of your variables and their usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in `Node` class, rename `intialize` to `initialize` (missing `i`)